# C# DataTables - Design Pattern Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, datatable, code-reuse

### ***Problem Statement***

I am working on a web application in Asp.Net. It has multiple modules and each modules have multiple ***`C# DataTables`*** which are being populated through `DataReader` and `DataAdapter`.

So for this purpose I have to initialize Datatable, specify its columns names and their DataType for each and every DataTable. Although in some cases, they contain my `DataBase's Tables Column Name` but while Traversing the DataTables, I have to specify columns which I want to Select and to get Data from Selected Row I have to specify Column Name explicitly.

It is very time consuming and I have to write so much of code for these operation in each module.

My requirement is that I want a Design Pattern (Like we implement Repository Pattern in MVC, etc) for DataTables which implement C# DataTables and provides `Property accessors` for Initialization of DataTables, Number of Columns of each DataTable, Columns Names and for traversing as well. Each DataTable should be independent of others.

### ***Possible Solution***

I have found that [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern is suitable for it. But I couldn't figure it out how to use it for C# DataTables in these specific scenarios so far.


any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
static DataTable MakeTable(Dictionary<string, Type> dict)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Type> row in dict)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(row.Key, row.Value);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: thanks @jdweng .. you are great buddy. it saved my head from DataTables and its columns initialization over and over again.. Although now i just need to create a `Dictionary` and add values into it, pass it to proposed method.. Now can you provide any efficient solution for `Traversing` of `DataTables`?...

Comment: The code is really simple enough you don't need to go through the effort of building a dictionary.  It is just one line of code to add a column to a data table.

Comment: yeah.. Now i am talking about Traversing of DataTable.. Is there any shortcut solution for it. i have tried `Linq`.. it is good and efficient.. if you have any suggestion then please share. and thank you for your effort. :-)

Comment: I usually use Linq to enumerate through a DataTable.  You can use Group By to speed up the enumerating or converting the DataTable to a Dictionary<key, List<DataRow>>.

Comment: ok.. one more thing to ask.. Suppose in DataTable i want to specify some Default value for a Column and want to add an Auto Incremented Column with its Increment Step and Seed values as well using your proposed solution.

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.71).aspx